# Is it possible to create a dashed box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a dashed box-shadow effect or create a similar CSS effect in a simpler way than this one: https://codepen.io/felpsio/pen/bGBZVgK ?

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.element {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
}

.element>div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content {
  background: lightgrey;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.aux-shadow {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border: 2px #ffd664 dashed;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="aux-shadow" />
</div>
```

I have to apply this pattern in my elements in one project and I'm trying to find a more scalable way to apply it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements instead of using another div, this makes it way easier to scale.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.element {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
}

.element > div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content {
  background: lightgrey;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
    /* ------ Add this: ----- */
    .content::before {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      left: 15px;
      border: 2px #ffd664 dashed;
      border-radius: 10px;
      z-index: -1;
    }

.aux-shadow {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border: 2px #ffd664 dashed;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="aux-shadow" />
</div>
```

Also, delete the z-index in .content.

Comment: I had to apply the pseudoelement on `.element` instead of `.content` because of the z-index. But thank you very much. It did work :)